# Element of the Weyl group acting on co-roots

Tags: root-systems, weyl-group, weights

Let $W$ be the Weyl group of a semisimple algebraic group defined over say $\mathbb C$. We have the root space $\mathfrak a^*$ spanned by the roots $\{\beta \in \Delta\}$ and also by the weights $\{ \varpi_\beta \in \hat\Delta \}$ which is a finite dimensional real vector space on which $W$ acts. Fix $w \in W$ and $\varpi \in \hat\Delta$. I would like to know why the vector $ ( \varpi - w \varpi ) $ is a non-negative linear combination of roots.

Reference: In [their Compositio paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/compositio-mathematica/article/on-the-continuity-of-arthurs-trace-formula-the-semisimple-terms/21E9B483BFBDDA8B78F037984FB56AA0), Finis and Lapid use this fact to prove Lemma 2.2 on p.788 saying that it is well-known but I am not able to prove it.

Comment: You meant to say "non-negative linear combination of roots in $\widehat{\Delta}$. Use Bourbaki, "Lie Groups and Lie Algebras", Ch. VI, section 1.6, Prop. 18 (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii) (proved by induction on the length of $w$) applied to the dual root system (whose Weyl group is the same!).  Here you need also that the Weyl group coming from Lie theory coincides with the Weyl group attached to the root system (i.e., the former is generated by the reflections in roots used to generate the latter by definition); hopefully this theorem belonging properly to Lie theory is one you already know.

Comment: Thanks! If you could post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Now I see you were in the setting of algebraic groups rather than Lie groups, so where I wrote "Lie theory" I should have said "the theory of algebraic groups" (over $\mathbf{C}$, but it works the same for split connected semisimple groups over an arbitrary field). A proper answer would include a reference on the equality of the Weyl groups for relating the combinatorial theory of root systems and the algebro-geometric theory of split connected semisimple algebraic groups.  I'll leave my comment as is; if someone wants to put something like it as an official answer they can feel free to do so.

Comment: My group is algebraic and in the question I intentionally said over $\mathbb C$ because I wanted $G$ to be split. The Weyl group "Normalizer mod maximal torus" (split case) is indeed that for the root system and any standard text on algebraic groups discusses that, say Springer Ch. 8. Nevertheless, you have cited the right reference.